# Extrude bones are not connected?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

[image]

I have extruded the bones from the trail side and all the bones are connected (on Left Side) and when the extruded on the head side of the bone, the new bones are not connected to the main bone.

The selected bone is the first bone from which i started creating armature

Am I doing something wrong ? Pl help

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74215/why-is-this-bone-suddenly-not-connected