# How to connect a bone to the root of another? Why did this work before and not anymore?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, extrude

I was following this tutorial (https://youtu.be/4z7G4TyKE9g) for an easier entry into rigging and something that the guy does (Blender 3.1, I use 3.6) there simply doesn't work (anymore?) and apparently isn't supposed to work according to other Blender users. The spine bone was the main bone from which the shoulders and arms were extruded. Then the guy from the video went on to extrude the hips and leg bones starting with the **root** (bottom) of the spine bone (link with timestamp: https://youtu.be/4z7G4TyKE9g?t=325), which made the bones connected. *This simply does not work anymore* and apparently isn't even supposed to work because bones are "onedirectional" ([Why is this bone suddenly not connected?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74215/why-is-this-bone-suddenly-not-connected)).

When he goes into pose mode and moves the spine bone, the whole armature moves with it (link with timestamp: https://youtu.be/4z7G4TyKE9g?t=516). In my case only the upper part of my armature moves because the bottom isn't connected, even though I did exactly what he did.

[image: My rig with the missing connection even though I followed the instructions]

[image: tutorial rig with connected bones for s o m e reason]

(I know that that the body looks off with the armature, but he fixes that later on. I am just talking about the fact that his armature is connected)

Now my questions: Why did this work at some point apparently (like in the guys video) and now doesn't anymore? How can I make this work? Because I can only find explanations to why it doesn't work and not on how to fix it. Is setting the bone as a parent with offset my only choice? That's the only thing I can come up with and I don't know if this is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the version he uses, when you extrude a bone from the head of another bone, the extruded bone is the child of the original bone, it doesn't work like that anymore, to fix it you need to stay in *Edit* mode and parent the hip bone to the spine bone with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Parent) > Keep Offset*.